# angular ionic white screen with Uncaught SyntaxError in vendor.js in inspect device mode

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

Checked from "chrome://inspect/#devices" for the white screen problem.

Console said "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token (    vendor.js:105268"

[image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/91X5D.png)
[image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HcflW.png)

How should I fix it in order to fix the white screen problem, even if I open the basic angular ionic project, still appear the same problem.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: The problem is solved, thanks.

Comment: hi @AlanTCP . how did you solved. me facing same issue. Please let me know.

Comment: hi @RajaSekaran. I solved this 1 year ago and can't remember exact. But that time I am upgrading the ionic version from 4 to 6. Also you may try to recover to the backup of your project coding and see if it can help. Finally, is there any packages you install and create this problem? I hope i can help you

Comment: Hi @AlanTCP, Thanks. Actually i am not getting this error in all mobiles, some models are only having this issue.

Comment: @RajaSekaran Also had the problem long time ago, since I do not have it anymore I'm not that sure, but I think my answer should solve your problem.

Answer (score -1):

For what I do remember, the issue can from the wrong `target` version in the `tsconfig` file.

Not every smartphone does accept the latest version.
See the [compatibility table](https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es2016plus/) to know more.

### TLDR

Inside your `tsconfig.json` file, use

```js
 "target": "es2015",
```

Comment: i am using same. but still i am getting same error